# C File I/O - Need to compare different stdin char with every line

Tags: c, file, input

So, I have this exercise here, what it is it's a quiz written in a file, each question has 2 answers and each question is in one line, where the last character before the newline is the correct answer. Given answers as well as the correct answers are separated with a '$'. This is how a sample file looks like:

```
Koja zemja koristi najmnogu elektrichestvo?$а)SAD$b)Kina$b
Koe e najchesto ime vo svetot?$a)Li$b)Muhamed$b
```

So, the program needs to print out one question along with both given answers, wait for an answer from stdin, and then check to see if the answer is correct. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //if(argc!=2) {printf("Upotreba: ./2 <vlezna datoteka>"); return -1;}
    FILE *read=fopen("kviz.txt", "r");
    //if((read=fopen(argv[1], "r"))==NULL) {printf("Ne postoi takva datoteka."); return -1;}
    int i=0;
    int j;
    char answer;
    char string[200];
    while(fgets(string, 200, read)!=NULL)
    {
        string[strlen(string)-1]='\0'; //remove newline
        for(i=0;i<strlen(string);i++)
        {
            if(string[i]=='$') string[i]=' ';
        }
        for(i=0;i<strlen(string)-1;i++)
        {
            printf("%c", string[i]);
        }
        answer=getchar();
        if(answer==string[strlen(string)-1]) {printf("Correct answer.\n"); continue;}
        else {printf("Incorrect answer.\n"); continue;}
    }
    fclose(read);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the program works for the first question, but it only lets me input an answer once. The output I get is:

```
Koja zemja koristi najmnogu elektrichestvo? а)SAD b)Kina b
Correct answer.
Koe e najchesto ime vo svetot? a)Li b)Muhamed Incorrect answer.
```

If you notice, after the second question I haven't inserted an answer, it just takes the answer i input first and compares it, and the comparison is bad as well since question 2 answer is also b and it prints that it is Incorrect. Any help?

Comment: `answer=getchar();` When you typed that answer, what do you think happened to the newline you entered *afterward* ? It is still sitting in the input buffer and the next `getchar()` will pick it up (which is your next answer read, and obviously neither `a` or `b`).

Comment: That is something I have not known so far. Thank you.

Comment: You should always check the returned value from I/O statements (like fopen() ) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the statement: 'continue;' is not needed as the code is already at the end of the while loop

Comment: Hi, the continue statement was just me testing something to see if I can make the code work. And the check for fopen() is there, I just commented it out for testing purposes of this program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getchar()` will get one character at a time.

When the user entering the answer and pressing enter, '\n' character is in the buffer.

So that the `getchar()` get the `'\n'` character when comes to second answer.

To avoid that,

put another `getchar()` after this line. Like,

```
answer=getchar();
getchar();
```

It will take the newline and program will work fine.

Comment: This will handled the specific case the OP has, but will not work in general as a mechanism for error correction. This assumes the user always inputs one char followed by something (anything really) that can be ignored. Input like `a \n`, `abc\n`, `\n\n`, etc, will all march on with invalid data. once the input falls out of the expected char-newline interleaving. At some time the OP needs to account for that as well. But for the immediate "this is why this problem happens" this answer is accurate, and ticked accordingly.